# Is there a timeout for Handler.postDelayed?

Tags: android, handler, postdelayed

If I want to start some action from the service via `Handler.postDelayed`, can I start that action a couple of days ahead? Or there is some king of timeout for this, e.g. 12 hrs, 24hrs, etc.?

I am asking this as I think that the action does not execute if I set it for 24hrs ahead.

```
mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * 60 * (24 * 60));
```

I am not sure about this and I just want to exclude this guess if the issue is not in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handler is not intended for jobs to be executed 12 or 24 hours later.  Use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) instead.

Comment: Oh. Can you give me more info? Why is not suitable? Does something reset it, like system?